# Am I on the right track? Writing a function in JS that must evaluate the number of pieces in an object category

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm a beginner, trying to get to the bottom of this, but very stuck! I need to write a function that takes an array of customer objects and returns a new array containing only the customers who have purchased more than 5 items.I think there may be a much easier way to do this, but I can't figure it out!  I created objects and was trying to use the .map to evaluate part of my array and return an array.  I've gotten it to return an array at this point, but that's the best I can do.  Can anyone help?  I tried adding TIA!

```js
function Customer (name, itemsPurchased, numberOfItems) {
        this.name = name;
        this.itemsPurchased = itemsPurchased;
    };
    
    
    var Customers = [
        new Customer("Tim", ["milk", "Coke", "butter", "chips"]),
        new Customer("Sam", ["flour", "sugar", "vanilla", "butter", "chocolate chips", "brown sugar"]),
        new Customer("Sally", ["turkey", "stuffing", "gravy"]),
    ]
    
    let over5Items = Customers.map(function(element) {
        return element.length
    })
    
    console.log (over5Items)
```

Comment: Is there anything not working with your code?

Comment: Change `return element.length` to `return element.itemsPurchased.length` and you're golden.

Answer (score 1):

You're actually looking for [`Array.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

`Array.map()` returns a new array with the same number of elements as input where each element is the result of the given function.

`Array.filter()` returns a new array where each input element passes the tests in the given function.

```js
function Customer (name, itemsPurchased, numberOfItems) {
    this.name = name;
    this.itemsPurchased = itemsPurchased;
};
        
var Customers = [
    new Customer("Tim", ["milk", "Coke", "butter", "chips"]),
    new Customer("Sam", ["flour", "sugar", "vanilla", "butter", "chocolate chips", "brown sugar"]),
    new Customer("Sally", ["turkey", "stuffing", "gravy"]),
];
    
let over5Items = Customers.filter(function(element) {
    return element.itemsPurchased.length >= 5;
});
    
console.log(over5Items);
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to use map, instead you want to use filter. Filter will ONLY return matching elements.

```js
function Customer (name, itemsPurchased, numberOfItems) {
        this.name = name;
        this.itemsPurchased = itemsPurchased;
    };
    
    
    var Customers = [
        new Customer("Tim", ["milk", "Coke", "butter", "chips"]),
        new Customer("Sam", ["flour", "sugar", "vanilla", "butter", "chocolate chips", "brown sugar"]),
        new Customer("Sally", ["turkey", "stuffing", "gravy"]),
    ]
    
    const over5Items = Customers.filter(element =>element.itemsPurchased.length > 5);
    
    console.log (over5Items)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have an error in your current map code. I have fixed it too, in the example.

To answer your question, you need to use the filter function to find the item you need. Here is a great article on the different ways you can get what you need from objects: https://medium.com/poka-techblog/simplify-your-javascript-use-map-reduce-and-filter-bd02c593cc2d

```js
function Customer (name, itemsPurchased, numberOfItems) {
        this.name = name;
        this.itemsPurchased = itemsPurchased;
    };
    
    
    var Customers = [
        new Customer("Tim", ["milk", "Coke", "butter", "chips"]),
        new Customer("Sam", ["flour", "sugar", "vanilla", "butter", "chocolate chips", "brown sugar"]),
        new Customer("Sally", ["turkey", "stuffing", "gravy"]),
    ]
    
    // how to extract all purchases with .map
    const allPurchases = Customers.map(function(element) {
        return element.itemsPurchased.length // firstly lenght has to be looking at your array
    })
    
    
    // how to filter to all over 5 purchases
    const over5Items = Customers.filter(customer => customer.itemsPurchased.length > 5);
    
    console.log (allPurchases)
    console.log (over5Items)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let over5Items = Customers.map((element) => {
    return element.itemsPurchased.length > 5;
})
```